# Test Coverage for visual basic project

Tags: vb6, code-coverage

We are developing a Visual Basic 6.0 project. We have written a library, which we were testing using vbunit and vbmock. But soon found that the tests were not maintainable. So, we decided to write tests using MBunit. Now, we want to know the test coverage. How can we do it?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only VB6 test coverage tool I know is http://www.aivosto.com/vbwatch.html Aivisto seems to have a generally good reputation for their VB tools.

Answer (score 0):

Look into NCover

Comment: The poster specifically asked about VB6 so NCover doesn't help :(